# Sending messages to Azure eventhub via nodejs asyncrhonously resends all previous messages

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm sending messages to my Azure eventhub and I followed the documentation reported on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send.

However the example reported there expects to send a SINGLE message, while I need to keep sending events at regular intervals. For this reason I tried to use the setInterval() function:

```
const { EventHubProducerClient } = require('@azure/event-hubs');

var connStr = 'Endpoint=sb://ev*******.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=06********=';

const eventHubName="tweetsin";
var i=0;

async function main() {
    const producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connStr, eventHubName);
    var batch = await producer.createBatch()
        .then(function (tx) {
            setInterval(function() {
                tx.tryAdd({body: "Hello World - " + i});
                producer.sendBatch(tx);
                console.log("batch sent successfully");
                i=i+1;
            },1000);
        });
    
    console.log("message sent successfully");
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The problem is that if I use it, I do not only send the latest message, but also all the previous ones!

How can I "empty" the buffer at every cycle? Thank you very much,

Comment: I'm no node expert but reading your code I would say you are just always adding to your batch without every clearing it (or creating a new batch) `tx.tryAdd()`

Comment: You're right, my question is actually how to "clear the buffer". Theoretically I should run producer.close(), but if I do it, the next tx.tryAdd() fails. And I can't even run producer.createBatch() another time, because this must be done OUTSIDE of the setInterval() block of code.

Comment: yes, again, no Node expert here, but in general (with other languages): you create a new batch every time you want to send one or more messages together. You do not recreate the producer. How you do the interval thing in Node is a different question then

Comment: Actually I don't want to send all messages together. Instead, since this is a potentially infinite events generator, I need to send a single message per second, without the previous ones; for doing that, I'd expect to re-create the batch variable at every iteration within setInterval(). And close() it at the end of the iteration.

Comment: no, you should not close the producer. but yes, you should create a new batch every second

Comment: ok, so I need help to clear my batch within setInterval() please. It's likely trivial, but I couldn't find the right way